# travis-ci ruby build with node 5

Tags: ruby, node.js, travis-ci

I've tried many things, but have ultimately failed to get the build for [gulp-pipeline-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails/blob/master/.travis.yml) running.  The `script` runs locally, no problem.

The last problem I've narrowed down is that I have a `ruby` language project that utilizes node, but [I need node 5](https://travis-ci.org/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails/jobs/118509845#L1461).  I found [one snippet](http://austinpray.com/ops/2015/09/20/change-travis-node-version.html):

```
#------------------------------
# Update the node version
env:
  - TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION="5"

install:
  - pwd
  - rm -rf ~/.nvm && git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm && (cd ~/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`) && source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install $TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION
  - npm install
```

While this seems to get node updated, it does something to my ruby env where it [fails to execute rspec](https://travis-ci.org/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails/jobs/118509091#L411):

```
$ pwd && bundle exec rake
/home/travis/build/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails
Could not find gem 'rspec' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

---

**Question**
With all that said, how do I simply use Node 5 with this `.travis.yml`?

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
  - ruby-head

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - rvm: ruby-head

cache: bundler

#------------------------------
# Setup
before_script:
  - node -v
  # update npm
  - npm install npm -g

  # install Gulp 4 CLI tools globally from 4.0 GitHub branch
  - npm install https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/tarball/4.0 -g

#------------------------------
# Build
script: bundle exec rake
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a `before_install` stage for [adding a second language](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Installing-a-Second-Programming-language) on Travis, maybe something like:

```
before_install:
  - nvm install node
```

`nvm` should be installed by default on the Travis build image (depending on which one you're using), and this command will install the latest version of Node.

After that, maybe just have `npm install -g gulp-cli@4.0` as the first step in your `before_script` stage (i.e. don't worry about updating npm), hopefully that should mean that bundler still runs fine and installs all your gems.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://entulho.fiatjaf.alhur.es/guias/how-to-use-node-along-with-other-language-on-travis-ci/) that helped me out quite a bit.

Relevant information from article:

You can use `nvm` to manage you node versions in travis, however you have to enable it first:

```
 install:
  - . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - nvm install stable
  - nvm use stable
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project's language is ruby, Travis CI will run `bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3` by default.

If you define an `install` stage yourself in `.travis.yml`, [the default will not execute in favor of the newly specified commands.](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby#Travis-CI-uses-Bundler) The thinking here is to have sane magic by default that should easily be overridden.

There are two solutions to this issue:

1. Add `bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3` to the `install` stage
2. Rename the header of the node replacement snippet to `before_install` as suggested by @ocean.